# Flutter - RefreshIndicator on a child of CustomScrollView

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver, customscrollview

So, I have a `CustomScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` and a `SliverList`. The `SliverList` has multiple non-sliver children widgets.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(title: Text('some title')),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
        [
          // non sliver children
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);
```

I want the content (non sliver children) of the `CustomScrollView` to have pull down to refresh. I don't want to put the `RefreshIndicator` on top of the scroll view because that will also reload the `SliverAppBar`.

I tried wrapping all the non-sliver children with a Column and wrapping that Column in the RefreshIndicator but that didn't work.

How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Wrap CustomScrollView inside RefreshIndicator.

Comment: I already tried that. I don't want the SliverAppBar to refresh too, which it would if I wrap the whole CustomScrollView inside RefreshIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

###### U can use like this.

```dart
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    CupertinoSliverRefreshControl(
      onRefresh: _refreshData,
    ),
    SliverList(
      delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate((context, index) {
        WordPair wordPair = _data[index];
        return _buildListItem(wordPair.asString, context);
      },
      childCount: _data.length,
    ),
  ],
),
```